# How do I get my site domain and hosting using php?

Tags: php, hyperlink

This way I link to my files in html and php.
Because by rewriting the url, the styles change and the face of the site becomes ugly.
But this method is not very good because it does not work on some sites.
Sample of my code:

```
<?php $domain = example.com ; $host = $_SERVER['HTTP-HOST'];?>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo "http://$host/$domain" ?>style.css" >
```

Comment: The domain in e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482294` would be `stackoverflow.com`, not `questions`. What are you trying to accomplish? You can omit host and domain entirely, you'd only need them in your CSS is hosted in an entirely different server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be come must be like this?

```php
<?php
$domain = 'example.com';
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if ($host === 'localhost') {
    $host .= "/$domain";
}
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo "http://$host/" ?>style.css" >
```

UPD: Added dynamin host naming for `localhost` host.

Comment: But this is not done in localhost.

Comment: @Parham, way to use hostname as first path item is not entirely correct. It is easier and more correct to configure a local web server to work with the required hosts as such. Anyway, I made edits in answer to domain support when opening a page through `localhost`.